# What name servers should I have for AWS route 53 DNS settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I have a website stored in AWS S3 bucket which I am trying to connect to a domain now in Amazons' route 53 and I have followed the tutorials to the T. I transferred a domain from GoDaddy to amazon this morning, I wrongfully selected to keep GoDaddy's DNS settings while doing the transfer. The issue of why my website was not working was because during the transfer I kept their nameservers. I removed the GoDaddy NameServers in Route 53s Registered domains page with these 4 nameservers I found inside the record sets. I get a 404 error. How do I find the correct nameservers for my domain?

Answer (score 0):

All hosted zones in Route53 contain an NS record entry with 4 values. Those are the values you would put in GoDaddy to have Route53 manage your domain.